animateFloatAsState don't stop
I tried to rotate an Icon() using animateFloatAsState.

    log("CurrentWeatherLayout", "refreshState:"+weatherInfo?.refreshState)


    val rotation: Float by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (weatherInfo?.refreshState == 0) -360f else 0f,
        animationSpec = InfiniteRepeatableSpec(
            animation = tween(
                easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing,
                durationMillis = 2000
            ), repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ), label = ""
    )
    Icon(
        tint = Color.Unspecified,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(40.dp)
            .graphicsLayer {
                rotationZ = rotation
            },
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_refresh),
        contentDescription = "refresh"
    )

When 'refreshState' is 0,Icon() starts to rotate,but when 'refreshState' is 1,Icon() startes to revers.
I printed 'rotation' value,When 'refreshState' is 1,The value will change from 0 to 360,But when 'refreshState' is 1,The value will change from 360 to 0.
Why is that? How do I stop animateFloatAsState from generating new values

Do you want it to keep rotating all the time or not? It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

I want it to stop, but after spinning counterclockwise, it starts spinning clockwise, and it can't stop @BenjyTec

I added an answer below. If it is helpful, please upvote it or mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer.

When you are using an InfiniteRepeatableSpec and a RepeatMode, the animation will run infinitely.
If you want the rotation to occur only once, you can try the following code:
var rotationDirection by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)  // true = clockwise, false = counterclockwise
}

Button(onClick = { rotationDirection = !rotationDirection }) {
    Text(text = "ROTATE")
}

val rotation: Float by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = if (rotationDirection) 360f else 0f,
    animationSpec = tween(
        easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing,
        durationMillis = 2000
    ), label = ""
)
Icon(
    tint = Color.Unspecified,
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(40.dp)
        .graphicsLayer {
            rotationZ = rotation
        },
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_refresh),
    contentDescription = "refresh"
)

Output:


In case you want the animation to always only rotate clockwise, you can use the following code:
var targetRotation by remember {
    mutableIntStateOf(0)
}

Button(onClick = { targetRotation = 360 }) {
    Text(text = "ROTATE")
}

val rotation: Float by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = targetRotation,
    animationSpec = tween(
        easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing,
        durationMillis = if (targetRotation == 0) 0 else 2000
    ),
    finishedListener = {
        targetRotation = 0
    },
    label = ""
)
Icon(
    tint = Color.Unspecified,
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(40.dp)
        .graphicsLayer {
            rotationZ = rotation
        },
    imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Refresh,
    contentDescription = "refresh"
)

